# 2d Spacetime Transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, physics

I have a spacetime in 2-dimensions.
 x is the position and t is the time.

[image: Img]

1) t is in nanoseconds and x in feet, so the straight lines may represent 2 opposite waves that overlap and move with the light's velocity.
Is that correct ?

2) What's the meaning to say : we may determine the transformations of this 2d spacetime which preserve straight lines and preserve the speed of light ?

Thanks so much

Comment: For fun: $x$ is in feet. Could it be in meters ?

Comment: Yes if t is 0.33*10^(-8) seconds

Comment: You understand humor... Then I proceed by concluding that your expression proves that metric system is awfully complicated.

Comment: This sounds more like a physics question than a mathematics one.

Comment: Hi @StephenG . Yes, it's a physical phenomenon but explained with linear trasformations ( = matrices )

Comment: When you say you "have spacetime in 2 dimensions", do you mean you are working in the 2-dimensional Minkowski space? If so, the lines $x = \pm t$ represent the boundaries of the timelike and spacelike cone. In this case, the transformations you ask for are the ones that respect the Minkowski metric, i.e. the Lorentz group. Or the Poincare group, depending on wheter you allow translations or not.

Comment: You are right man ! But whats the intuitive meaning of  "transformations that preserve straight lines and preserve the speed of light" ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Compare your setting to the one of Newtonian mechanics, where one works in $\mathbb{R}^4$ with one time and three space coordinates. How can you change your inertial frame of reference? Well, any change should preserve time intervals, spatial distance of simultaneous events and motions of free particles.
It turns out that you can translate or rotate your frame of reference, and you can move it by constant velocity.
This group of transformations is also known as Galilean transformations.

Now, in special relativity you work within the $2$-dimensional Minkowski space, i.e. $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the "inner product" $(t,x) \cdot (t', x') := -t \cdot t' + x \cdot x'$.
In general one would of course use $\mathbb{R}^4$, but let's just ignore that.

Now you do the same thing as in Newtonian mechanics: You think of properties that should stay the same when you change to another inertial frame of reference.
You definitely want to preserve the light cone $-t^2 + x^2 = 0$, as this is basically the mathematical analogue of "the speed of light is constant".
If you want to determine the group of transformations that preserves the light cone, it turns out that Galilean transformations are not suitable for this, but the Lorentz group (or Poincaré group) is!

A useful reference may be chapter 2.7 of "Peter Szekeres – A Course in Modern Mathematical Physics: Groups, Hilbert Space and Differential Geometry".